# I have a 2000 Suzuki Grand Vitara 5 Speed Ticking noise

Tags: transmission, suzuki, gears, differential, grand-vitara

I hear a ticking noise coming from the driver side rear end, possibly coming from the differential, not sure though because i checked out the pinion gear and i don't see any chips off any of the teeth, the noise usually begins when i'm in 2nd gear and get it in between 2 thousand and 3 thousand RPMs. Its usually on and off, but once and awhile when i push in the clutch and coast to a stop sometimes it starts making a loud clunking noise that doesn't sound pleasing. Anybody who could help out and try to figure this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you feel the clunking in your floorboards as well as here it ?

Comment: I can a little bit, it comes and goes, now its mainly when im coasting or i push the clutch in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think worn-out rubber. Sway bar end bushings, sway bar (middle) bushings, shock absorber bushings.

A worn out U-Joint or CV joint can also cause tick and thump noises.